# Wrong vertical align of text in Google Chrome browser

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, vertical-alignment, google-webfonts

I have problem with creating "button" element (text in inline-block container with border), because in some font-size text has wrong vertical-align (is not perfect middle).

I want to use [**Raleway**](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Raleway) (Google Web Font) and [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).
Height of the text container is set by line-height.

I am testing it on **Windows 7**...

on **Firefox** (ver. 36) everything is perfect
[image: Firefox (ver. 36)]

but the problem is on Google **Chrome** (ver. 41)
[image: Google Chrome (ver. 41)]

Live preview: http://biznes-dynamit.pl/test/marcin-dobroszek/font/

Part of CSS code:

```
/*Bootstrap default style*/
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/*custom style*/
body {
    font-family: "Raleway";
}
.btn {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-size: 11px; /*real height: 8*/
}
.btn-sm {
    font-size: 10px; /*real height: 7*/
    line-height: 15px;
 }
.btn-lg {
    font-size: 12px; /*real height: 8-9*/
    line-height: 16px; /*light, normal*/
 }
```

---

As you can see in Chrome preview in some font-size and font-weight **text is go up** relative container.

3x zoom sample, with font-size: 11px (line-height: 16px) and font-weight: semi-bold. 
[image: wrong vertical space]

Top and bottom space (between text and top/bottom border) should be the same: 4px, but as you can see top space has 3px and bottom has 5px.

Is it possible to fix this browser issue?

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem in one project, very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

This very annoying problem is caused by chrome not taking `text-transform: uppercase` into account. Use the following to get correct centering in Chrome with all-caps text:

```
text-transform: lowercase;
font-variant: small-caps;
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fyvyB/76/

Works great for buttons, for other usecases you might have problems with the text being small-caps and not real caps.

[image: Correct centering in chrome & ff]

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue with a custom font. After some playing around and trying all different display properties on the text element, I noticed that the vertical align issue only affected text elements whose parent was `display: block;`, despite said text element being set to `display: inline;`. I resolved the problem by changing parents to `display: table;` and the child text elem to `display: inline;`, e.g. below... I can't explain why this worked, but posting here in case it helps others...

```
<style>
  div {
    display: table;
  }
  span {
    display: inline;
    padding: 5px 10px; /* to make v-alignment clearer */
  }
</style>
<div>
  <span>Some text here</span>
</div>
```